# i want to update only single record in cassandra using expressjs

Tags: express, cassandra

when im using insert query for update it work correctly but when im using update for the same it genrate error 404. my code is below:

```
router.post('/updateone', function (req, res, next) {

var id = req.body.id;
var fn = req.body.f;
var ln = req.body.l;
var email = req.body.e;

var query = 'UPDATE stu SET email=?,firstname = ?,lastname=?  WHERE id=?';
    //var up = 'insert into stu(id,email,firstname,lastname)values(?,?,?,?)';
client.execute(query, [email,fn,ln,id], function (err, result) {
    if (err) {
        res.status(404).send({msg: err});
    } else {
        res.send(result);
    }
});
});
```

Comment: What is the table schema?

Comment: and what is in the error message?

Comment: id  |   email      |   firstname  |   lastname

Comment: POST http://localhost:3000/updateone 404 (Not Found)

Comment: This is a message from HTTP framework, not from Cassandra. Just print error message to console... Also, regarding the schema - show the CQL definition with primary key, etc.

Comment: execlty what im saying that when i use insert for update than it work but not with update query. this error not occur when i use insert query for update record

Comment: id and email are primary key fields

Comment: please tell me that is there is any mistake in my code

Comment: FYI- Updates and inserts are the *same* in Cassandra.  If it worked with INSERT, that should be good enough.  Also, you cannot update PRIMARY KEY columns in Cassandra.  You will need to build a data model which does not key on email, in order to update it.

Comment: okay. i want to ask that how to apply unique key constraint on email in case email is not primary key. also is there is unique key in cassandra

Answer (score 1):

When you're updating the row, you need to specify all components of the primary key - in your case this is `id` & `email`, but you're specifying only the `id`.

From [documentation](https://docs.datastax.com/en/cql/3.3/cql/cql_reference/cqlUpdate.html):

> The WHERE clause specifies the row or rows to be updated. To specify a row, **the WHERE clause must provide a value for each column of the row's primary key**. To specify more than one row, you can use the IN keyword to introduce a list of possible values. You can only do this for the last column of the primary key.

Comment: can i write like this:-----var query = 'UPDATE stu SET email=?,firstname = ?,lastname=?  WHERE id=? && email=?';

Comment: `var query = 'UPDATE stu SET email=?,firstname = ?,lastname=? WHERE id=? AND email=?';`